# Convert Between Floating Point Standards

Tags: c++, floating-point, ieee-754

I am trying to convert an IEEE based floating point number to a MIL-STD 1750A floating point number.

I have attached the specification for both:
[image]

I understand how to decompose the floating point 12.375 in IEEE format as per the [example on wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_precision_floating-point_format)

However, I'm not sure if my interpretation of the MIL-STD is correct.

12.375 = (12)b10 + (0.375)b10 = (1100)b2 + (0.011)b2 = (1100.011)b2
(1100.011)b2 = 0.1100011 x 2^4 => Exponent, E = 4.

4 in normalised 2's complement is = (100)b2 = Exponent

Therefore a MIL-STD 1750A 32 bit floating point number is:

```
S=0, F=11000110000000000000000, E=00000100
```

**Is my above interpretation correct?**

**For -12.375, is it just the sign bit that swaps?** i.e.:

```
S=1, F=11000110000000000000000, E=00000100
```

Or does something funky happen with the fraction part?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The diagram above is a bit misleading, I think.  In IEEE format, to switch from positive to negative, you simply flip the first bit.  The remaining three bits can be treated as an unsigned number.  In the MIL-STD format, the mantissa is a two's complement number, so while the first bit does indicate the sign, the remaining 23 bits do not remain the same.

What I get is

```
S=1, F=00111010000000000000000, E=00000100
```

Comment: so it seems you make the fraction 1100011 2's complement => 0011101, however the remaining bits in the fraction component are still 0's?

Comment: Yes, to take the two's complement negation, take the bitwise NOT and add one:  so when you take the bitwise not, you end up with 16 1's on the far right, then when you add one, they all carry over.